# Fast and free server for computing

Tags: hpc, differential-equations, cloud-computing

I have to calculate a huge differential equation. With my laptop, it's going to be computed for several days.

Is there a free (I need just for 3 days) fast server for scientific calculations?
My calculations are not parallelized, and in fact, are computed on 1 core.

I tried [Google free server](https://cloud.google.com/free/), however, looks like it's not faster than my laptop.

Comment: Unless your laptop is really old, it would be difficult to find a free service that is faster.

Comment: Which citizenship do you have? The US, for instance, has compute resources freely available for researchers.

Comment: If you provide more details it might be easier to help you. What equation are you solving? What method are you using? What does "huge" mean, how many degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will certainly benefit from parallelization of your code (or using/switching libraries that offer a native parallelization). So **it might be worth looking into parallelization** depending on your priorities in terms of time and possibility of new upcoming simulations.

In terms of external computing resources, I would say, that you are looking for a very rare unicorn here. It would be hard to satisfy all three criteria and be in the centre of the Venn diagram.

Here, by "Universal", I mean no limitation to one particular technology, no strict time limitations (trial period), and, the most important one, citizenship & affiliation of the user.

[image]

Example services:

- **Fast** and **universal**: many now available cloud-based services: [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/), [IBM cloud](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/), and several others. The downside is that the cost is not very cheap and certainly not free.
- **Free** and **universal**: [Free tier of Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), [Free tier of IBM cloud](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free/), which obviously would have a lot of limitations on the available computational resources and might not be faster than your laptop.
- **Fast** and **free**: [XSEDE](https://portal.xsede.org/) would provide US-based institutions with computational resources. Limitations: you have to have a collaborator who has access to those resources. Similar things would exist for other regions, but usually, they would be limited to researchers having affiliation with a limited set of institutions.
- **Free**: (not necessarily fast or unlimited) free-trials to new services. [Intel Xeon Phi Cluster from Fujitsu](http://www.fujitsu.fr/page/remote-access-program), limited to Xeon Phi's.
- **Fast**: your own hardware. It may be the cheapest or the most expensive in terms of price, depending on the circumstances.
- **Fast**, **Free**, and **Universal**: don't know anything that even comes close to be in this group according to my definitions.

Relevant posts:

- [XSEDE for researchers outside the USA](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15884/20688)
- [2012 similar request with a bit scattered answers](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1376/20688)
- [undergraduate needs cores for his project](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28922/20688)
- [Discussion on Fujitsu Xeon Phi Cluster](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28752/20688)